# Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_audiofile'

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to convert .mp4 file to .mp3 using moviepy(Python)
Here is the code I am running.

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

video1 = askopenfilename()

video = VideoFileClip(video1)
audioclip=video.audio
audioclip.write_audiofile("Sample.mp3")

video.close()
audioclip.close()
```

But , I am receiving this Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Email Automation/delete.py", line 22, in <module>
audioclip.write_audiofile("Sample.mp3")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_audiofile'
```

I have tried to follow up the code from almost every Source , but I am receiving this error.

Comment: `video.audio` is retuning `None`

Comment: @zr0gravity7 I copied the same code from the following Youtube video Link - https://youtu.be/u5x5RZNtOqE

Comment: @zr0gravity7 Even this video has the same code - https://youtu.be/i3vaJMitpjo

Comment: Then perhaps your video has no audio. The [docs](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html?highlight=videofileclip#:~:text=audio%20(default%20None)) say the default is None.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Yesss , you are right. I just checked my .mp4 video had no audio. My Doubts are cleared and the program is also running Good. What should I do now ?? Should I delete the question ??

Comment: No need, it may help others. I would ask @JustinEzequiel to consider making his comment an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the problem !
The video(.mp4) I was trying to convert had no audio in the video.
Therefore , the error occurred due to No Audio in the file.
The [docs](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html?highlight=videofileclip#:%7E:text=audio%20(default%20None)) say the default is None.

Credits: Justin Ezequiel